# Не работает $.each на объекте

Tags: jquery, объекты, each

Подскажите, может, я чего-то не замечаю.

Цикл $.each вообще не запускается. Object.keys(lesson_work_types) возвращает пустой массив, getOwnPropertyNames тоже. For(let i in lesson_work_types) тоже не работает.

Что не так?

UPD:
[image: код и результат]

Comment: напишите в вопрос что внутри `lesson_work_types`

Comment: Так написал же.

Comment: а, понял.......)

Comment: вы наверное не подклxили jquery?

Comment: либо у вас нет такой переменной https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQfcM.png

Comment: А «не работает» чем проявляется? Здесь усё работает...

Comment: Вот и мне интересно, почему.

Comment: Потому что это не полный приведённый вами код. Ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Может, я неправильно создаю объект? 
let lesson_work_types = {};
lesson_work_types['01.02.2021'] = [true, 'url']

Comment: так-то так, но как будто это не весь код...... jquery-то хоть подключен? Ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: Обновил пост. Это реальный код, между циклом и выводом результатов ничего нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в асинхронности. Объект менялся во время вывода.